# Finding the tercile from a List of objects

Tags: java, quantile

I need help how to compute tercile. Example of my dataset:

```
ImmutableList<Double> DataSet = ImmutableList.of(25.0, 100.0, 0.0, 144.0, 9.0, 121.0, 4.0, 225.0, 169.0, 64.0, 49.0, 16.0, 36.0, 1.0, 81.0, 196.0);
double[] dataset = Doubles.toArray(DataSet);
```

I tried to use [Google Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/29.0-jre) to compute the median but I don't know how to use it to compute the tercile:

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.primitives.Doubles;
import com.google.common.math.Quantiles;
import com.google.common.math.Quantiles.ScaleAndIndexes;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImmutableList<Double> DataSet = ImmutableList.of(25.0, 100.0,
                  0.0, 144.0, 9.0, 121.0, 4.0, 225.0, 169.0, 64.0, 49.0, 16.0, 36.0, 1.0, 81.0, 196.0);
        double[] dataset = Doubles.toArray(DataSet);

        double median = Quantiles.median().compute(dataset);
        System.out.println(median);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tercile is 3-quantile.
Guava has this method:

```
public static Quantiles.Scale scale(int scale)
Specifies the computation of q-quantiles.
Parameters:
scale - the scale for the quantiles to be calculated, i.e. the q of the q-quantiles, which must be positive
```

So you can do

```
Quantiles.scale(3).compute(...)
```

UPD

It seems Guava (and Google) has it's own notion of terciles. It takes actual values into account, and finds tercile based on value rather that index.

If that's not what you are after, and what you need is just plain index-based tercile, you don't really need a library for that, just write it yourself (obviously you need to sort your data first, and take into account corner cases):

```
static double[] terciles(double[] data) {
    data = data.clone();
    Arrays.sort(data);
    int len = data.length;
    if (len < 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    double result[] = new double[2];
    result[0] = data[len/3];
    result[1] = data[2*len/3];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answe. Please Can you tell me if this is correct : <pre>Map<Integer, Double> largeValues = Quantiles.scale(3).indexes(1, 2).compute(dataset);
  double p1 = largeValues.get(1); 
  double p2 = largeValues.get(2); 
  System.out.println(p1);
  System.out.println(p2); <code>

Comment: @Farida looks correct but I suggest you try it first and see.

Comment: this is the entire code: import java.util.Map;
import com.google.common.math.Quantiles;

public class MAIN {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   
 double[] dataset = {158.0,158.0,160.0,160.0,163.0,163.0,163.0,164.0,165.0,166.0,167.0,170.0,171.0,172.0,193.0,187.0,190.0};<br/>
  Map<Integer, Double> tercile = Quantiles.scale(3).indexes(1,2).compute(dataset);<br/>
  double q1 = tercile.get(1); 
  double q2 = tercile.get(2);
  System.out.println("Les terciles sont:");
  System.out.println("q1=  "+q1);
  System.out.println("q2=  "+q2);
  
 }

}

Comment: the result is: Les terciles sont:
q1=  163.0
q2=  169.0

Comment: @Farida see updated answer. Depending on what you need you probably don't need a library

Comment: @Dmirty, in my case I am interessted to the values not to the index so I think I must use the librairie. I try to run the code that you write above, the result is (q1=163.0, q2=170.0) different from the result given by my code. I add I try on Excel by q1=percentile.exc(dataset, 1/3) and q2=percentile.exc(dataset, 2/3), I get q1=163, q2=170.

Comment: @Farida I don't know your assignment so I can't advise which result is correct. If you know that Excel gives you correct result, that means you should be using the code I provided. Normally, tercile definition is the points dividing the data into 3 equal groups, which is usually meant to imply that it is index-based, as Excel suggests.